# Is heavy an adjective of quality or an adjective of quantity

Tags: adjectives

> The bus sustained **heavy** damage in the accident

In the above sentence, is ***heavy*** an adjective of quality or an adjective of quantity?

Adjectives of quantity refer to how many or how much of something and adjectives of quality refer to the kind, degree, or quality of something.

heavy can be telling us how much of damage is done. It is also telling us the degree of the damage.

Comment: It doesn't really make any difference - I certainly can't distinguish "how much damage" from "the degree of the damage". The bus was ***badly damaged***, and unless you use a lot more words, we don't know if, say, only the engine at the front was crushed, or all the windows along the entire length of the bus were broken and the roof got completely ripped off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, "heavy" is an adjective of **quantity**.

Here's the appropriate definition from Merriam-Webster:

> **8 :** greater in quantity or quality than the average of its kind or class: such as
> **a :** of unusually large size or amount
> *a heavy turnout*

So the phrase "heavy damage" means a large quantity of damage. It does not describe any quality of the damage, like how it affects the performance of the bus.

Answer (score 0):

'Heavy' is not an adjective of quantity.

Adjectives of quantity, as the name implies, *quantify* things - they comment on the *amount* or *volume* of countable and measurable things. Adjectives of quantity include *“few”, “several”, “much”,* and *“more”*.

'Heavy' describes something's relative weight. But weight is not directly linked to size or quantity - a rock is heavier than a balloon the same size.

It is true that 'heavy' can be an intensifier - for example *heavy rain* - and this does not always refer to weight. But it variably means something like *dense*, *hard-hitting*, or *intense*. I can't think of any case where it refers to quantity or size, volumetrically speaking.

Comment: The adjectives of quantity answers the question 'how much'. So, heavy can answer how much as answered by @gotube. Am I correct?

Comment: If heavy here indicates severe or serious damage, then it is adjective of quality and if it indicates a lot of damage, then it is adjective of quantity?